# Merge two tables while doing operations

Tags: sql

I'm currently creating two tables using SQL but I need to Union them and it's not clear how to do this when group bys are involved

```
Select ...
group by email, column 1
```

Which creates two tables like this:

```
Table1
+--------------+----------+
| email        |  Column1 |       
+--------------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |  
+--------------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |  
+--------------+----------+


table2
+--------------+----------+
| email        |  Column1 |       
+--------------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |  
+--------------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |  
+--------------+----------+
```

I want to merge them using a union into this

```
TableTotal
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| email        |  Column1 |  Column2 |  Column3 | 
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 1            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| 2            |    x     |    x     |    x     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```

But I don't know how to use union when I'm also grouping the selections. When I try to do it, I get the error "column1 is ambiguous".

Answer (score 1):

You need UNION ALL or UNION (removes duplicates).

```
SELECT ... GROUP BY ...
    UNION ALL
SELECT ... GROUP BY ...;
```